# Retrieving all grounds within a distance

Tags: database, geometry, coordinates

[A picture that describes the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSi4e.jpg)
I have a database consisting of land details and the latitude longitude coordinates of its corners. Is there any way to retrieve all the lands from database that fall within an area covered by extending the four corners of a land by some distance?
Thank You.

Comment: This type of problem would usually be solved by postcode area and then a  boundary flag applied to a group of postcodes - you can also achieve the same by using lat-long and grouping particular ranges to an area - you need to think how you will structure the data first - may I suggest some of the GIS packages available as these allow you to compartmentalise certain ranges of lat-longs effectively - a suite of products that spring to mind are ARC-GIS backed by PostGres

Comment: Can you please share some link where I can find information regarding these?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the installation files for PostGIS from here:

http://postgis.net/install/

You can download the PostGres DB binary suites from here:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/

You can download the management studio PGAdmin from here:

https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: Can you help me regarding how to approach the problem? You mentioned about postcode area and boundary flag. A brief explanation or link regarding these would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: There is a help page explaining all of the necessary elements here, please research how you could achieve what you are after from here:  https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html

Comment: another good resource is the open data-sets on postcode boundaries, https://census.ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/boundary-data

Comment: Thank You. I will go through these links.